# Cuda : use the global memory to store contiguous various size datas

Tags: pointers, memory-management, cuda, gpgpu

I have a problem using a buffer of bytes in global memory to store some integer of various size (8 bits, 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits).

If i store an integer at an pointer value non multiple of 4 bytes (for instance because i just stored a 8bit integer), the adress is rounded down, erasing the previous data.

```
__global__ void kernel(char* pointer)
{
    *(int*)(pointer+3)=3300000;
}
```

In this example code, using any of : (pointer), (pointer+1), (pointer+2), (pointer+3) the integer is stored at (pointer), considering pointer is a multiple of 4.

Is cuda memory organised in 32 bit blocks at the hardware level ? 
Is there any way to make this work ?

Comment: Why not just use `int` pointers and let the *compiler* decide the best alignment? You know, the piece of technology that hundreds of experts have designed to work as best with the hardware as possible?

Comment: Because i have to store various size data : char, int, long long int, etc. In my project, i can not afford to use int pointer and lose 24 bits of memory each time i need to store a char. (The equivalent code works perfectly fine in C, so i seem to be a Cuda specificity).

Comment: Cuda requires word sized alignment. It is non negotiable. You can't cast a non-32 bit aligned address to a 32 bit type.

Comment: Apart from the fact that certain hardware will simply not *permit* broken alignment (up to and including hardware traps and crashes), you may very well also incur dramatic performance hits if you force something like this on a more lenient hardware like x86, so that even if this were to work, it might very well destroy any benefit you would have got from the GPU hardware in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your comments, they are very helpful. I rekognize it wasn't a great idea, but in this case i was very concerned by the memory use optimisation. Anyway, I'll manage to adapt my code to this constraint !

Comment: Ndech consider writing a custom assign function... see my answer for more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word size alignment is non-negotiable in CUDA.  However, if you're willing to take the performance hit for some reason, you could pack your data into char * and then just write your own custom storage function, e.g.

```
__inline __device__ void Assign(int val, char * arr, int len)
{
   for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
      *(arr+idx)=(val & (0xFF<<(idx<<8))
}

__inline __device__ int Get(char * arr, int idx, int len)
{
   int val;
   for (int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
      val=(int)(*arr[idx+len*idx]<<(idx<<8)));
   return val;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! I will try your solution to find the optimal trade-off between performance and memory use optimisation for my application.